# Batch import of data from .txt files - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have multiple .txt files each containing the same format.

I've been reading these into MATLAB individually using:

```
fid1 = fopen('Test_1.txt','r'); 
data = textscan(fid1, '%f %*f %f %f %f %*[^\r\n]','HeaderLines',4);
```

And using `cell2mat` to extract the values from there.

How can I batch import all .txt files and store them all?

So far I detect the relevant files to important using:

```
files = dir('Test_*.txt');
```

But I am not sure how to then batch import each .txt file in the above manner using a loop.

Comment: Do you know in advance the number of rows in each file? Btw you got all the 'ingredients'. You just need the loop and to store the read variables where/how you want, e.g. in a single matrix.

Comment: It seems you already asked the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844005/batch-import-of-txt-files-by-filename-matlab .  Please, refrain from asking duplicate questions!

Comment: Just figured it out now (see: EDIT). Out of interest, is there a more efficient way to do this without using a loop?

Comment: you should probably add your solution as an answer and accept it so others can see the problem is solved more easily and also delete the duplicate of this question mentioned by brodroll

Comment: @AnnaSchumann Good that you figured it out! You could post that as a solution, instead of editing the question. I am not aware of a better way to read multiple files (with headers) without a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clear
data = {};
files = dir('Test_*.txt');
for i=1:length(files)
    fn = files(i).name;
    fid1 = fopen(fn,'r');
    data{1,i} = textscan(fid1, '%*f %*f %f %f %f %*[^\r\n]','HeaderLines',4);
end
```